# use wifi for data but not phone?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 and figured out how to connect to WiFi, but I want only the data to go through WiFi, not the telephone calls. (I have had trouble w/ phone over wifi; the data is fine though + it saves me money going through WiFi.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since when do phone calls go via WiFi? Are you talking about some VoIP app (e.g. SIP)? Standard telephony goes via your mobile provider, WiFi connected or not.

Comment: It's builtin to my phone. Not a VoIP app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha, found it:

under apps -> settings -> connections, I can turn overall use of Wi-Fi on or off.

[image]

Then if I select "More networks", I get this screen:

[image]

and I can turn on or off "Wi-Fi Calling".

Tmobile has a note about it here: http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-5864

Answer (score 0):

All the telephone calls go through Mobile network not Wifi. If you have any VoIP application like Viber or Skype installed. Then while making call, it asks whether you want to use Phone or Viber/Skype. I guess you might have selected one of these apps with "Always" settings.

In this case, go to Application Settings & Clear Defaults. And next time be sure of selecting Phone Always.

Comment: No that's not true. My phone can use wifi for regular phone calls, I'm not using skype or anything like that.

Comment: But that's quite unusual: cell phones use phone cells (to phone phones at other cells, yeah ;). Do you have a reference link, so we can better understand what it is about?

Comment: I wonder if it's a Tmobile thing only. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2417990,00.asp "The S 4 also supports T-Mobile's excellent Wi-Fi calling system."

Comment: http://t-mobile-coverage.t-mobile.com/4g-wireless-broadband-service